How to scrape all customer reviews?
I am trying to scrape all reviews in this website - https://www.backmarket.com/en-us/r/l/airpods/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17. The website says there are 753 reviews, but when I try to scrape all reviews, I get only 10 reviews. So, I am not sure how to scrape all 753 reviews from the page, Here is my code-
# importing modules 
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Fetch the web page
url = 'https://www.backmarket.com/en-us/r/l/airpods/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17'
response = get(url) # link exlcudes posts with no picures
page = response.text

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# To see different information
## reviewer's name 

reviewers_name = soup.find_all('p', class_='body-1-bold') 
[x.text for x in reviewers_name]

name = []

for items in reviewers_name:
    name.append(items.text if items else None)

## Purchase Data 

purchase_date = soup.find_all('p', class_='text-static-default-low body-2')
[x.text for x in purchase_date]

date = []
for items in purchase_date:
    date.append(items.text if items else None)


## Country 

country_text = soup.find_all('p', class_='text-static-default-low body-2 mt-32')
[x.text for x in country_text]

country = []

for items in country_text:
    country.append(items.text if items else None)


## Reviewed Products 

products_text = soup.find_all('span', class_= 'rounded-xs inline-block max-w-full truncate body-2-bold px-4 py-0 bg-static-default-mid text-static-default-hi')
[x.text for x in products_text]

products = []

for items in products_text:
    products.append(items.text if items else None)

## Actual Reviews 

review_text = soup.find_all('p',class_='body-1 block whitespace-pre-line')
[x.text for x in review_text]

review = []

for items in review_text:
    review.append(items.text if items else None)


## Review Ratings 

review_ratings_value = soup.find_all('span',class_='ml-4 mt-1 md:mt-2 body-2-bold')
[x.text for x in review_ratings_value]

review_ratings = []

for items in review_ratings_value:
    review_ratings.append(items.text if items else None)



# Create the Data Frame 
pd.DataFrame({
    'reviewers_name': name,
    'purchase_date': date,
    'country': country,
    'products': products,
    'review': review,
    'review_ratings': review_ratings
})

My question is how I can scrape all reviews.

You can probably automate pressing the 'show more' button until they are all loaded, or read the code behind the button to see if there is an API or something you can (ab)use to directly access the data you want.

@NickSlash I pressed "show more", but still it extracts only 10 reviews.

@Sharif - the additional reviews are probably being dynamically loaded on demand via JS, so you'll need to use a tool like Selenium or Playwright to actually render the page in a webbrowser, trigger the dynamic loading, and then scrape

@nigh_anxiety I never used Selenium or Playwright. Can you provide some small code on how I can use them? Thanks

There are dozens of posts on SO and also many, many guides online for how to use Selenium. Here's one such example on SO for scraping a dynamically loaded table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75740686/how-to-scrape-a-dynamically-loaded-table-inside-a-webpage

based on your expectations, I think using the requests library and a little bit of code can fetch your desired result, here is my mindmap:
we can use this https://www.backmarket.com/reviews/product-landings/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17/products/reviews API endpoint to fetch all of your expected information related to reviews. (I guess UUID in the URLs is your product ID, correct me if I'm wrong)
Note: The site has rate limit protection in so I used time.sleep(5) to minimize thread
Here is my code:
import time
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_data(content):
    result = content['results']
    for i in result:
        first_name = i['customer']['firstName']
        last_name = i['customer']['lastName']
        name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
        rating = i['averageRate']
        review = i['comment']
        date = i['createdAt']
        prod = i['product']['title']
        prod_img = i['product']['imageUrl']
        country = i['countryCode']
        
        
        print(f"reviewers_name:  {name}\npurchase_date:  {date}\ncountry:  {country}\nproducts:-----------\nproduct_name:  {prod}\nproduct_img:  {prod_img}\n---------------------\nreview:  {review}\nreview_ratings:  {rating}\n============================")

def gather_cursor(url):
    n, cursor_and_url = 1, url
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        response = requests.get(cursor_and_url, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        get_data(data)
        cursor = data['nextCursor']
        if not cursor:
            break

        cursor_and_url = f"{url}?cursor={cursor}"


gather_cursor("https://www.backmarket.com/reviews/product-landings/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17/products/reviews")

Hope this will help.

just saw @Andrej Kesely answer this question : ))

Can you share how did you identify this url - https://www.backmarket.com/reviews/product-landings/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17/products/reviews

Hey, I used Burp Suite (a proxy tool by Portswigger) to capture all the HTTP requests then I saw this particular requests were made from apps when I clicked the see all review button. Screenshot is here: link

Thanks for sharing.

You can try (note: the site has "Too many requests" protection, so when you get HTTP status code 429 you have to wait some time before continue):
import time
import requests


url = "https://www.backmarket.com/reviews/product-landings/345c3c05-8a7b-4d4d-ac21-518b12a0ec17/products/reviews"

n, current_url = 1, url
while True:
    response = requests.get(current_url)

    # too many requests?
    if response.status_code == 429:
        print("Too many requests...")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue

    data = response.json()

    for r in data.get("results", []):
        print(n, "-" * 80)
        print(r["comment"])
        n += 1

    next_cursor = data.get("nextCursor")
    if not next_cursor:
        break

    current_url = f"{url}?cursor={next_cursor}"

Prints:

...
748 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ordered space gray but received silver
749 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lately, every item we’ve ordered has had to be returned. I’m pretty bummed.
750 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
They broke.
751 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
They’re weren’t noise cancelling like it says in the description so it wasn’t what I wanted but other than that they are great.

